# Excel Formula - If any cells within a range contain specific value, then

Tags: excel-formula

I don't quite know how to word this one, but unable to write the correct formula.

I've written =IF((AND((COUNTIF(B:B,B31)),C31 = "Comp")), "yes", "no") which is clearly wrong.

Below is an image of the document:

[image]

What I'm trying to do is create a formula that will look at all the **Unit Numbers** in Column B, and check if the work orders have been completed in column C (With COMP indicating completed, and blank indicating not) and then say either yes or no in column E. The problem is that I need column E to say no if any row with the same unit number does not have all of its work orders completed.

So unit 101 would all say YES.
Unit 102 would say NO, because two Work Orders have not been completed, etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=COUNTIF(B:B,B2)=COUNTIFS(B:B,B2,C:C,"COMP")` this would return `TRUE` for all completed and `FALSE` if any still not completed. If you want it to actual say `Yes` or `No`, wrap it in `IF()`.

Comment: This is great, thanks a ton P.b! works perfectly.